# how many ways to make change, asymptotics

Tags: asymptotics

This is a simplified coin-changing question.
Suppose the only coins available are all powers of $10$ dollars.
How many ways are there to make change for $\$ 1000000$?
In general, to make change for any amount \$$N$, the answer is $C(N)$, where 
$$C(N)=C(N-10)+C(\lfloor N/10 \rfloor )$$.
That is because the change may either include at least ten \$1 coins,
and there are $C(N-10)$ solutions; or fewer than ten \$1 coins, and the remaining coins are all multiples of ten, and there are $C(\lfloor N/10 \rfloor )$ solutions.
My question is: What are the asymptotics of this recursion, as $N$ grows large?

[EDIT]

Thankyou for the search tip.  I found it in a 1948 paper in Indagationes Math X "On Mahler's Partition Problem".  NG De Bruijn cited Karl Mahler's 1940 paper from Journ. London Math Soc. "On a special functional equation".  His formula, for base $10=r$ and number $N=rh$ was
$$ \log C(rh)=\frac{1}{2\log r}\left(\log\frac{h}{\log h}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\log r}+\frac{\log\log r}{\log r}\right)\log h\\-\left(1+\frac{\log\log r}{\log r}\right)\log\log h+O(1)$$

De Bruijn went on to calculate the $O(1)$ which was a periodic but not differentiable function.
Well, that's sorted me out.

Comment: You switch without warning from 1,000,000 to $N$. Please edit to do something about that.

Comment: The corresponding sequence for powers of 2 is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A018819 and many references and links are given. If asymptotics are known, they are probably available at one or another of those references, and then you can see whether the arguments can be adapted to powers of 10.

Comment: Thankyou, I found it in a 1948 paper in Inagationes Math X.

Comment: Good!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Why the downvote?