# Partitions of a prime power into powers of the same prime

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

Fix a prime $p$, and $k$ a natural number. The question is then:

How many partitions of $p^k$ are there into powers of $p$?

So, for instance, if $p = 2$ and $k = 2$, there are 4, namely (4), (2, 2), (2, 1, 1) and (1, 1, 1, 1).

This seems like it could be a hard problem in number theory, but I don't really know much number theory (I'm a topologist), and so don't have a feel for such things.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A002577 is p=2

Comment: http://oeis.org/A018818 is also cool (the equivalent question for all positive integers, not just prime powers)

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2325075 has some bounds on the number

Comment: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=469864 (online at http://www.dli.gov.in/rawdataupload/upload/insa/INSA_2/20005a84_1276.pdf) is related too, take m=n to be a prime power. if you are looking at conjugacy classes in p-groups, this could provide a very nice result when the centralizer sizes or conjugacy class sizes are bounded.

Comment: (That's probably all I've got to contribute. Number theory isn't my thing, but this is a nice question.)

Comment: Your example is confusing, since $2\cdot2=2+2$. Since you want an additive partition, I might suggest giving an example with $p=3$.

Comment: Let $f(n)$ count the number of partitions of $n$ into parts consisting of powers of $p$. Observe that in each such partition, the number of parts equal to $1$ is itself congruent to $n$ mod $p$. The number of such partitions with precisely $m$ ones (given $n\equiv m$ mod $p$) is $f\left(\frac{n-m}{p}\right)$. Therefore $$f(n)=f\left(\frac{n-r}{p}\right)+f\left(\frac{n-r}{p}-1\right)+f\left(\frac{n-r}{p}-2\right)+\cdots$$ is a recursive formula satisfied by $f$, where $0\le r<p$ is the residue of $n$ mod $p$.

Comment: Furthermore a generating function for $f(n)$ is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)x^n=\prod_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-x^{p^n}\right)^{-1}.$$ For a group theory interpretation, it is also the case that $f(n)$ counts the number of ${\bf Z}(p^\infty)$-sets of order $n$ (see [group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action)), where ${\bf Z}(p^\infty)$ stands for the [Prüfer $p$-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group). @alex.jordan I don't see what $2\cdot2=2+2$ has to do with the question.

Comment: @anon When I saw the question, at first I thought OP meant multiplicative partitions like $2^2$, $2^1\cdot2^1$. Not additive partitions like $2^2$, $2^1+2^1$, ... I'm just saying that an example with $3$ in place of $2$ would help prevent anyone else from that misinterpretation.

Comment: I think the examples (4), (2,2), (2,1,1), (1,1,1,1) collectively being highlighted as partitions of $4$ is perfectly sufficient to dispel that potential confusion. | Oops, I was confusing subgroups with quotients. I mean ${\bf Z}_p$-sets, where ${\bf Z}_p$ denotes the $p$-adic integers. Probably not relevant anyway.

Answer (score 2):

My question 428904, "how many ways to make change, asymptotics" asked the same question and I found the answer in a 1948 paper in Indagationes Math X "On Mahler's Partition Problem". NG De Bruijn cited Karl Mahler's 1940 paper from Journ. London Math Soc. "On a special functional equation". His formula, for base $p=r$ and number $N=rh$ was
$$ \log C(rh)=\frac{1}{2\log r}\left(\log\frac{h}{\log h}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\log r}+\frac{\log\log r}{\log r}\right)\log h\\-\left(1+\frac{\log\log r}{\log r}\right)\log\log h+O(1)$$
De Bruijn went on to calculate the O(1) which was a periodic but not differentiable function.
$C(rh)$ obeys the functional equation $C(rh)=C(rh-r)+C(h)$.

Comment: It might have been kind to provide a [link to your earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428904/how-many-ways-to-make-change-asymptotics)

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: See [help on formatting links](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) or use the link icon above the edit box