# solve $T(n)=T(n-1)+T(\frac{n}{2})+n$

Tags: recursion

Using the recursion tree i tried solving this: $T(n)=T(n-1)+T(\frac{n}{2})+n$; the tree has two parts (branches) one that of $T(n-1)$ and other branch is of $T(\frac{n}{2})$. But as the term T(n-1) reach higher depth, I solved that part of the tree. Finally it resulted in O$(2^n)$ is it correct or is it $O(n^2)$? How can we solve it by substitution method?

Comment: If $T(n) = O(n^3)$, say $T(n)=Mn^3+...$, then the leading order of the right-hand side is $M(1+1/8)n^k$ - that is, $T(n)$ is defined to be a bit bigger than $Mn^k$.  I think $T(n)$ grows faster than any polynomial.

Comment: The function $T(n)=-2n-2$ works.  Also, if $U(n)=T(n)+2n+2$, then $U(n)=U(n-1)+U(n/2)$ without the final $n$.

Answer (score 11):

If you want a final answer, skip to the last line.

$T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n/2) + n$

The problem is at least $O(n^2)$.  My guess is that the $T(n/2)$ contributes $log(n)$.

So let's check if $T(n) \in O(n^2 log(n))$

Does there exist $M$ such that as $n$ gets large:

$$\exists M>0, n_0, \forall n > n_0, T(n) \le M n^2 log(n) $$

Known: $T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n/2) + n$

substitute known recursion into $T(n) \le M (n^2 log(n))$ :

$$T(n - 1) + T(n/2) + n \le M n^2 log(n)$$

$$T(n - 1) + T(n/2) \le M n^2 log(n) - n$$

We need 2 inductive hypothesis to check this, so we'll be using super violent strong induction:

$$\text{Inductive hypothesis:}$$
$$T(n - 1) \le M (n - 1)^2 log(n - 1)$$
$$T(n/2) \le M (n/2)^2 log(n/2)$$

We have inductive hypothesis of the forms $a < b$ and $c < d$ , we wish to use that to prove a statement of the form $a+c < e$, so we need to establish that $b+d < e$

$$M (n - 1)^2 log(n - 1) + M (n/2)^2 log(n/2) \le M n^2 log(n) - n$$

So we want to find if there is any $M$ that doesn't depend on $n$, that for a sufficiently large $n$, makes the above statement true.

$$M ((n - 1)^2 log(n - 1) + (n/2)^2 log(n/2) - n^2 log(n)) \le - n$$

$$M (n^2 log(n - 1) - 2nlog(n - 1) + log(n - 1) + 1/4n^2 log(n) - 1/4n^2log(2) - n^2 log(n)) \le -n$$

$$M (n^2 (log(n - 1) - 3/4 log(n) -  1/4log(2)) - 2nlog(n - 1) + log(n - 1) ) \le -n$$

The coefficient of $n^2$ is $log(n - 1) - 3/4 log(n) -  1/4log(2)$, which you can see by inspection will be positive for sufficiently large $n$. Unfortunately, since $M$ must be positive, and the right hand side is negative, that means that no value of $M$ will make the equation true for sufficiently large $n$.

Therefore we cannot conclude that $T(n) \in O(n^2 log(n))$.  One step in the above was an implication rather than an equivalence, so we can't necessarily say that it is false either.  We'll check another bound.

---

Let's see if any polynomial satisfies this.  Is $T(n) \in O(n^c)$ for some c.

$$T(n) \le M n^c$$

Known: $T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n/2) + n$

substitute known recursion into $T(n) \le M n^c$ :

$$T(n - 1) + T(n/2) + n \le M n^c$$

$$T(n - 1) + T(n/2) \le M n^c - n$$

2 inductive hypothesis again:
$$T(n - 1) \le M (n - 1)^c$$
$$ T(n/2) \le M (n/2)^c$$

We have inductive hypothesis of the forms $a < b$ and $c < d$ , we wish to use that to prove a statement of the form $a+c < e$, so we need to establish that $b+d < e$

$$M (n - 1)^c + M (n/2)^2 \le M n^c - n$$

So we want to find if $\exists M, \forall n > n_0, \text {above statement holds}$.  Let's ignore all polynomial terms of degree less than $c$, since we are only concerned with $n$ above a threshhold.

$$M ((n - 1)^c + (n/2)^c - n^c) \le - n$$

$$M (n^c + \frac{1}{2^c} n^c - n^c + \dots) \le -n$$

$$M \frac{1}{2^c} n^c + \dots \le -n$$

So we can't find any polynomial which seems to solve this.

---

I think someone suggested checking if $T(n) \in O(n^{log(n)})$.  That would be an interesting result.

$$T(n) \le M n^{log(n)}$$

Known: $T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n/2) + n$

substitute known recursion into $T(n) \le M n^{log(n)}$ :

$$T(n - 1) + T(n/2) + n \le M n^{log(n)}$$

$$T(n - 1) + T(n/2) \le M n^{log(n)} - n$$

2 inductive hypothesis again:
$$ T(n - 1) \le M (n - 1)^{log(n - 1)}$$
$$ T(n/2) \le M (n/2)^{log(n / 2)}$$

...blah blah blah

$$M (n - 1)^{log(n - 1)} + M (n/2)^{log(n / 2)} \le M n^{log(n)} - n$$

$$M ((n - 1)^{log(n - 1)} + (n/2)^{log(n / 2)} - n^{log(n)}) \le - n$$

$$M (n^{log(n)} - (n - 1)^{log(n - 1)} - (n/2)^{log(n / 2)}) \ge n$$

At this point it's pretty obvious that we've found a solution.  Yay.  Try $M=1$.

$$n^{log(n)} - (n - 1)^{log(n - 1)} - (n/2)^{log(n / 2)} \ge n$$

This holds for $n > 5.4$, a witness for $n_0$.

Therefore we can conclude that $T(n) \in O(n^{log(n)})$.

We can all be happy now. Please double check this for typos.

Comment: A nice bit of work!  There are three equations in a row beginning with $M$; the sign of the right-hand side changes going from the first to the second row.  Could you check that?

Comment: You are right, I'm going to see what I can do to fix it now.  I have to check a larger O() bound.  Sad.  Oh well I'll leave the first part in and change up the second.

Comment: @Michael thanks for your observation, I believe I have established $O(n^{log(n)})$ as you suggested above.

Comment: CLRS (3/e, problem 4.4-5) missed "starring" this problem to indicate this is a tough one. This is a much harder problem than many of the others they have starred.

Comment: What about a matching lower bound?

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Michael's answer, let $S(n) = T(n) + 2n + 2$. Calculation shows that
$$
S(n) = S(n-1) + S(n/2).
$$
(This is assuming that by $n/2$ you actually mean $n/2$ rather than $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ or the like.) [Mahler](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/mahler/docs/068.pdf) showed that every function satisfying the very similar functional equation $S(n+1) = S(n) + S(n/2)$ has the asymptotic form
$$
S(n) = \Theta\left( \sum_{m=0}^\infty 2^{-m(m-1)/2} \frac{n^m}{m!} \right) .
$$
A function satisfying our functional equation probably has the very same asymptotic form.
Stirling's approximation gives
$$
2^{-m(m-1)/2} \frac{n^m}{m!} \sim \frac{n^m}{\sqrt{2\pi m}(m/e)^m \sqrt{2}^{m(m-1)}}.
$$
Taking logarithm of the $m$th term, we get roughly
$$
m\log n - \Theta(m^2).
$$
This is maximized for $\log n = \Theta(m)$, at which case the value of the logarithm is $\Theta(\log^2 n)$. We deduce that the sum itself is roughly
$$
\exp \Theta(\log^2 n) = n^{\Theta(\log n)}.
$$
Therefore (modulo some inaccuracies),
$$ T(n) = n^{\Theta(\log n)}. $$

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question earlier this year, and found a technical paper on 
it from 1948.  Even without the extra $+n$ at the end, the formula was pretty cool.

[how many ways to make change, asymptotics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428904/how-many-ways-to-make-change-asymptotics)

For this problem, without the floor function, try $T(n)=an+b$, and solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: So, is this the solution is O(2^n)? I still have a confusion with the solution.

Comment: I think there is one particular solution that is linear.  But most of the solutions, if I read the formula correctly, are $O(n^{\log n})$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Dear Yuval Filmus, you right and I got it.
I edited my wrong, thanks.
I think we can look at it this way:

$T(n)=2T(n/2)+n < T(n)=T(n−1)+T(n/2)+n < T(n)=2T(n−1)+n$

Now it is very clear that we have:

$Θ(n*\log n) < Θ(T(n)) < Θ(2^n)$

And finally your solution is righ.
But it will take a lot of range of functions. Is there any idea how to reduce this range? 
I have a few ways, but I'm not sure. For now I just guess:

Θ(T(n)) = Θ( 2^(log (logn)))

This can be true?