# Solving this recursive function $f(x)=f(x-k)+f(x/k)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

How to solve or simplify the following recursive function?
$f(x)$ is defined only for whole numbers as follows:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \mbox{if } x<k; \\
                     f(x-k)+f(x/k) & \mbox{if } x\ge{k} \mbox{ and } k \mbox{ divides } x;\\
                     f(x-1) & \mbox{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Here $k$ is a positive integer $\le10$.

Comment: did you try generating the first terms ? Can you give us some sample ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the number of different ways to write $x$ as the sum of powers of $k$
I found the solution in a 1940 paper, that I copied into the following question: 
[how many ways to make change, asymptotics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428904/how-many-ways-to-make-change-asymptotics)

Comment: Why is it the number of different ways to write x as sum of powers of k ?

Comment: Can you give a proof for that ?

Comment: @kingcobra Set up the recurrence. Make it conditional on the existence of a $k^0$ term. Note that $k\leq 10$ is not a required condition.